# How can the Java simulate string input?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I want to simulate keyboard inputs, using the Java Robots Class

How can I simulate characters like `æ` ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you please explain more?

Comment: @mserioli your link not relevant  here,

Answer (score 2):

Easily use the ASCII Code, which is 146 for `Æ` and 145 for `æ`

or use Unicode, which is U+00C6  for `Æ` and  U+00E6 for  `æ`

Comment: To send a key press with Robot you need to use a virtual key code, not the Unicode character code. No vk code exists for keys like æ on Danish keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use alt + numberpad

http://tools.oratory.com/altcodes.html

`æ` = hold Alt whilst typing 1,4,5 (on the numberpad) then release Alt

Comment: Well, u can do in this way, but how about type a Japanese characters? For example, this: じ

Comment: Easy! Hold alt, type 12376 on the numberpad, release alt. No problemo!

Answer (score 0):

You can input `Unicode` value of that character. You may need to change your code which accept `Unicode` value.